# Eclipse font preferences

Tags: eclipse, workbench, user-preferences

Trying to set a font size below 8 in Eclipse 3.7 I stubled upon a line in

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
```

---

This is the line:

```
org.eclipse.jface.textfont=1|Envy Code R|7.75|0|WINDOWS|1|-11|0|0|0|400|0|0|0|0|3|2|1|49|Envy Code R;
```

Someone knows what the various pieces (devided by a `|`) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is the string returned by the `toString()` method of `FontData`. This value is platform specific, you will have to inspect the `FontData` source code for your platform to determine exactly what it means.

The `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter` class provides various methods for converting `FontData` to/from this string.

Comment: I added my answer for everyone with the details for Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Greg input, this is how the string is formed.
The first part seems to be platform independant.

```
1      |Envy Code R|7.75  |0
version|name       |height|style
```

The rest is platform dependant.

```
WINDOWS |1       |-11     |0      |0           |0            |400     |0       |0          |0          |0        |3             |2              |1        |49             
platform|version2|lfHeight|lfWidth|lfEscapement|lfOrientation|lfWeight|lfItalic|lfUnderline|lfStrikeOut|lfCharSet|lfOutPrecision|lfClipPrecision|lfQuality|lfPitchAndFamily
```

And in Windows is represented by the Class

```
public abstract class LOGFONT {
    public int lfHeight;
    public int lfWidth;
    public int lfEscapement;
    public int lfOrientation;
    public int lfWeight;
    public byte lfItalic;
    public byte lfUnderline;
    public byte lfStrikeOut;
    public byte lfCharSet;
    public byte lfOutPrecision;
    public byte lfClipPrecision;
    public byte lfQuality;
    public byte lfPitchAndFamily;
    public static final int sizeof = OS.IsUnicode ? OS.LOGFONTW_sizeof () : OS.LOGFONTA_sizeof ();
}
```

which is obviously a "copy" of the C struct:

```
typedef struct tagLOGFONT {
  LONG  lfHeight;
  LONG  lfWidth;
  LONG  lfEscapement;
  LONG  lfOrientation;
  LONG  lfWeight;
  BYTE  lfItalic;
  BYTE  lfUnderline;
  BYTE  lfStrikeOut;
  BYTE  lfCharSet;
  BYTE  lfOutPrecision;
  BYTE  lfClipPrecision;
  BYTE  lfQuality;
  BYTE  lfPitchAndFamily;
  TCHAR lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
} LOGFONT, *PLOGFONT;
```